# Sql Query information

Tags: sql

What does this do in a SQL Query? Can someone explain? What does the .5- represent?

WHERE ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate >= getdate() and ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate <= getDate() +.50

Comment: your questions are not clear. Explain with more details

Comment: `GETDATE() + .50` adds half a day to the current time.  So the query will pull all of the records where the `ScheduleDate` is between now and 12 hours from now.

Comment: Ideally, to add 12 hours to the current date, you would use `DATEADD(HOUR, 12, GETDATE())`, as `GETDATE() + 0.5` is just ambiguous unless you know that it represents days.  *"`0.5 what?"*

Answer (score 1):

Think of date unit as 1 day.  0.50 of a day is 1/2 of a day.  So this returns anything that has ScheduleDate within half a day from getdate() time forward.

Answer (score 0):

It restricts the rows returned to rows where the `ScheduleEntry.ScheduleDate` is in the future and where it is not more than .50 units later than the current date. To find out how much time .50 units is equal to, run the following on your console:

```
SELECT getDate()
SELECT getDate() +.50
```

The difference between the dates should tell you the difference. Most likely, it is half a day.

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE returns the current date and time in SQL.
You can use addition to "add days" to the current date. 
Generally, it is better to use DATE_ADD instead of adding directly and is probably easier to read. Adding 0.5 is akin to adding half a day (or 12 hours).

Answer (score 0):

To better illustrate, the .5 is half a day

```
SELECT DateDiff(HH,getDate(),getDate() +.50)
```

Returns 12 hours